# Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-geocoder

I am using [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem, its working fine. Now I m tried to upgrade with google_premier getting below error

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > Geocoder.search("Hyderabad")
Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON.
 => []
```

I am added new file in config/initializers/geocoder.rb, Here is my config setup

```
Geocoder::Configuration.lookup = :google_premier
Geocoder::Configuration.api_key = "xxx-key"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment the api_key line on your Geocoder configuration to avoid geocoder sending it. Google geocoder DOS NOT need the API Key...

Geocoder.rb example:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
Geocoder.configure(
    :timeout  => 5,
    :lookup   => :google,
    #:ip_lookup => :google,
    #:api_key  => "xxxx-xxx",
    :units    => :km
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. And my solution may be silly, but it worked for me. My solution was to reinstall the gem.